# Passing arguments to custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive with angular but can't find a way to pass the parameters I need to show in it.

The directive is being created like this:

```
(function () {
"use strict"; 

angular.module("directives", [])
    .directive("task", task);
function task() {
    return {
        scope: {
            Status: "=",
            Assignment: "=",
            Assignee: "="
        },
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Content/partials/task.html"
    };
}
}());
```

This is the HTML file:

```
<div>
<span class="assignment">{{ Assignment }}</span>
<span class="assignment">{{ Assignee }}</span>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="backTask($event, task)">Back</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="advanceTask($event, task)">Next</button>
</div>
```

And this is how I'm adding it:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:{Status: 0}">
<task Status="task.Status" Assignment="task.Assignment" Assignee="task.Assignee"></task>
```

The "directives" module is already being added to the main module:

```
(function () {
    const app = angular.module("kanbanTest", ["directives"]);
}());
```

I know the reference is working, since  the divs are being created in the document, but they show up empty leading me to believe the issue lies on the parameters.

Comment: just add them lower case and it will be fine status, assigment, assignee

Comment: I've tried making everything lowercase and it's still not passing the arguments correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving arguments like task-status, task-assignment , task-assignee

and in the directive definition use them as taskStatus , taskAssignment , taskAssignee